# Jsoup not working properly

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm not sure exactly what it's the problem. Whether Jsoup is not following the link or I'm doing something wrong.

```
String s = "http://www.sears.com/search=canon 70-200?pageNum=1&viewType=list";
Document d = Jsoup.connect(s).get();
System.out.println("Content: " + d.toString());
```

This should output the html code of the website, however I get empty header and empty almost everything. There is no information.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably look like this:

```
final String url = "http://www.sears.com/search=canon%2070-200?pageNum=1&viewType=list";
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get ();
System.out.println("Content: " + doc.toString());
```

The space character in the URL should be replaced with `%20`.

Comment: There was a small typo. But that's what I have, except final.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried replacing space with %20 and got the same result.